# Object is possibly 'null' after null check

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Can anyone let me know why the below code still get `Object is possibly 'null'` error even though I already checked whether event is null or not?

```js
  const handleImageChange = (event: Event) => {
        if (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
            const selectedFile = event.currentTarget.files[0]; // ERROR:Object is possibly 'null'!
            if (selectedFile) {
                setFieldValue("photo", selectedFile);
            }
        }
  };
```

Comment: you sure its not saying the event.currentTarget object could be null?

Comment: @about14sheep You are right. I should check `event.currentTarget`. I did not check it because the error message I see has an arrow pointing to `event` directly. Now after null check `event.currentTarget`, the error is gone. Thanks!

Comment: @about14sheep please provide an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should introduce a null check before picking the file in index "0".

```
   const handleImageChange = (event: Event) => {
            ...
            const { currentTarget } = event;
            if (currentTarget.files.length === 0) return
            const selectedFile = event.currentTarget?.files[0];
            ...
        }
  };
```